# How to Limit integer digits in a table in SQLite

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, ios6

How to Limit integer digits in a table in SQLite in a programatical way in ios?

Eg: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIMINGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Phone no INT (5), TIMING TEXT)";

we have to limit the phone no to 5 digits.

It is the right way or wrong way ????

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support digit limit numbers.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this with a `check` constraint.  See the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

The particular syntax would be something like:

```
create table . . .
    check (phonenum between 0 and 99999);
```

Alternatively, just make the phonenum a five character field -- you then cannot store more than five characters.

Comment: @user3045524 In SQLite, `(5)` is ignored.

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIMINGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, check (phonenum between 0 and 99999, TIMING TEXT)"; is correct as per your analysis??? @LS_dev

Comment: I always put constraints after the definition of all the columns, so I'm not sure if the ordering works.  But yes, the idea definitely works.